# What does %:p:h mean in vim?

Tags: vim

I know `:cd %:p:h` will change the working directory to the dir for current editing file. But what's the magic in `%:p:h`?

Comment: You should also be able to do `:cd %:h` to the same effect.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

From http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#filename-modifiers,

> :p    Make file name a full path.
>
> :h    Head of the file name (the last component and any separators removed)

Comment: The modifiers can also be looked up directly in vim: `:h %:p`.

Comment: Unfortunately `%` (in this context) can't be looked up with `:h`, so you can easily get lost in the documentation unless you have a little more context—which this answer provides. Thanks!